# Modal Dialog checkbox issue Google Chrome, IE, Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, modal-dialog

I can't check/uncheck any checkboxes in Google Chrome in my modal dialog and in IE when the dialog is initially loaded it works correctly, but if the dialog is closed and re-opened with the exact same data, even re-running the code to populate the dialog i can't check/uncheck checkboxes in there either. I have tried the z-index fix from other threads i've read which solved the issue initially in IE of not being able to check any of the boxes, but in chrome it still persists.

My dynamically created code is

```
<div id="IndividualReports" class="ui-dialog ui-widget" style="height: auto !important; width: 725px; background-color:white; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header " style="background-color: #00447B; height:50px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; padding:13px 0px 0px 25px;">
      <span id="ui-dialog-title-dialog" class="ui-dialog-title" style=" font-size: 20px; color: white;">Processed 1-Clicks</span>
   </div>
   <div style="width: 698px; height:25px; text-align:right; padding:5px 20px 5px 5px; background-color: white;">
        <a href="#"><img src="/applications/images/Refresh.gif"/>Refresh</a>
   </div>
   <div id="indOrdersList" style="width: 698px; height:350px; display:block; padding:5px 10px 5px 15px; background-color: white;">
        <table style=\'width: 685px;\' cellpadding=\'0\' cellspacing=\'0\'>
        <tr>
            <td style=\'width:20px;\'><a href=\'#\' class=\'toggleReportTwo\'></a></td>
            <td style=\'width:315px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold;\'>Sample Report Two</td>
            <td style=\'font-weight:bold; width:140px; text-align:right;\'>10/3/2013,9:52:40 AM</td>
            <td style=\'font-weight:bold; width:150px; text-align:left; padding-left:6px;\'>
                <a href=\'#\' class=\'viewIndReports\'>View All in One PDF</a>
            </td>
            <td style=\'width:70px;\'>
                <input type=\'checkbox\' id=\'delAllSampleTwo\' class=\'delAllSampleTwo\'/>All
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id=\'sampleTwoReports\'>
        <table style=\'width: 685px;\' cellpadding=\'0\' cellspacing=\'0\'>
            <tr>
                <td style=\'width:20px;\'></td>
                <td style=\'width:315px; text-align:left;\'>CHIN KIM</td>
                <td style=\'width: 140px; text-align:right; padding-right:4px;\'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style=\'width:150px; text-align:left; padding-left:6px;\'>
                    <a class=\'viewIndReports\' href=\'#\' target=\'_blank\'>View</a>
                </td>
                <td style=\'width:70px;\'>
                    <input type=\'checkbox\' id=\'delCHIN KIM\' class=\'delTwo\'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>  
   </div>
   <div style="height:75px; width:700px; background-color: white; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right; padding-right: 20px;">
        <input type="button" class="CommandButton" style="width:100px;" value="Delete Report(s)" onClick="deleteOneClickReports();"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="button" class="CommandButton" style="width:56px;" value="Close" onClick="closeIndReports();"/>
   </div>
</div>


    $('.delAllSampleTwo').live('click',function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $('.delTwo').prop("checked",true);
        }else{
            $('.delTwo').prop("checked",false);
        }
    });
```

I understand i don't have a live click() function for the individual checkboxes being created with the .delOne and .delTwo class names, do i need those as well?  I just figured a checkbox should be able to be checked.
Thanks for any help,
Nick G

Comment: Does your rendered HTML actually have all those backslashes in it?

Comment: not in the actual source, that's just the data dumped from the function i have creating the data in Jquery/Javascript

Comment: can you put it into a js fiddle?

Comment: i made it into a fiddle, but of course it works correctly within the fiddle, it's just tough because there is so much other stuff happening on this website, with include files and stuff i had nothing to do with that i'm sure that has to be breaking the functionality somewhere.  Here's the fiddle anyway, but it works as inteded; http://jsfiddle.net/Gtg3g/